# How to disassociate myself from Community Wiki answers I post?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, community-wiki, disassociation

I have posted a few Community Wiki (CW) answers. This was as a result of:

1. Removing the answer part from the question and posting it as a CW answer.
2. Converting some good helpful comment(s) to CW answer.
3. Mention some important activity done by OP out of the Stack Overflow which helped them to fix the problem. Example: OP also post the problem on GitHub and they get the answer there.

These answers keep showing under my user profile in the **Answers** tab. Them being there is not a problem for me. But, it is not useful to me at all. It is very unlikely that I will go to those answers in future. As those are CW, anybody can freely update them if needed.

As those are good(?) *answers* (NOT Not An Answer), I do not want to delete them either. Deleting them does not serve the purpose of why I posted them in the first place. I just do not want to see them in my profile.

How to disassociate myself from Community Wiki answers I post?